# python throwing some error while trying to load spacy

Tags: python, nlp, installation, package, spacy

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string


stops = stopwords.words('english')
stops.extend(['none'])

import nltk

import re
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess # for tokenizing
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
from sklearn.feature_extraction import stop_words

import spacy
```

Error is :

---

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>        20 from sklearn.feature_extraction import stop_words
>        21 
>   ---> 22 import spacy
>        23 
>        24 import pyLDAvis
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy__init__.py in 
>        10 from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
>        11 
>   ---> 12 from . import pipeline
>        13 from .cli.info import info as cli_info
>        14 from .glossary import explain
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline__init__.py in 
>         2 from __future__ import unicode_literals
>         3 
>   ----> 4 from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
>         5 from .pipes import TextCategorizer, Tensorizer, Pipe, Sentencizer
>         6 from .morphologizer import Morphologizer
>
> pipes.pyx in init spacy.pipeline.pipes()
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\syntax\nn_parser.cp37-win_amd64.pyd in init spacy.syntax.nn_parser()
>
> AttributeError: type object 'spacy.syntax.nn_parser.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Comment: What version of Cython do you have?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this error? What are your versions? Have you tried to update cython, spacy, sklearn etc?

Comment: I tried uninstalling thinc and cymem and then re-installing spacy. It doesn't do the job.

Comment: How do I check the version of Cython ? @GPhilo

Comment: ```import sys;
print(sys.implementation)
```